# What is the difference between "defined" and defined in javascript?

Tags: javascript

When writing this in javascript, I have seen it written in two different ways:

```
if (typeof x === "undefined") {
// execute code here
}

if (typeof x === undefined) {
// execute code here
}
```

my question here is:

what is the difference between `"undefined"` and `undefined`. One is enclosed in quotes and the other is not.

Can anybody clarify this for me?

Thanks!

Comment: `"undefined"` is a string containing the letters `u`, `n`, `d`, etc... `undefined` (no quotes) is a javascript variable.

Comment: The first is a string, the second is a primitive value of `undefined` type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`undefined` is a value, `'undefined'` is a string literal.  The `typeof` operator returns a string that gives you the type.  So `typeof x` returns the string name of the type of `x`.

Use `if( x === undefined )` or `if( typeof x === 'undefined' )` but never `if( typeof x === undefined )` because `typeof x` will always return a string (which will never equal `undefined`).

Comment: actually, undefined could be defined as "undefined" in which case `if(typeof x === undefined)` would evaluate identically to `if(typeof x === "undefined")`

Comment: If you do this, I will find you.

Answer (score 0):

`"undefined"` is a string, and `undefined` is a variable containing the primitive **value** `undefined` (Thank you elclanrs).

`if(typeof x === undefined)` should only ever be able to return true if `undefined` is reassigned to a string matching the type of x.

Comment: "is a variable, which is probably undefined" --- that's not correct

Comment: You can't set a variable with name `undefined`, it's a reserved global that represents *undefinedness*...

Comment: `undefined` is indeed a variable, that you can give any value you want, unless you `use strict`

Comment: @elclanrs "is indeed a varaible" --- as per specification or implementation?

Comment: @zerkms I don't think the spec says anything about the global `undefined` variable, but all implementations provide it afaik.

Comment: @zerkms `undefined` is certainly not a reserved keyword, which makes it an identifier, constant or not.

Comment: @elclanrs if a specification does not state that - it's not correct to interpret it like so.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan it doesn't make it a variable either. A standard [clearly defines](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.9) it as a "primitive value". So it's no different from any other primitive value, like `42` (which you would never call a variable)

Comment: @zerkms, actually, seems to be defined in the spec. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1. I think we are talking about different things. `undefined` is a variable with value `undefined` which is of type `Undefined`

Comment: @elclanrs it is, but the thing is that as a "primitive value" it is not required to be resolved as a global object attribute (it's an implementation specifics, not the standard requirement). Do you expect `42` to be resolved as a `global['42']`?

Comment: @zerkms a "value" is actually unrelated to this discussion. A value is what an identifier may evaluate to. The variable `a` may evaluate to `1` or `{}`. That doesn't make `a` a primitive or not. `a` is just an identifier, not a value. Same for `undefined`. The spec didn't completely defined `undefined`, so impls were free to represent it as an ordinary identifier.

Comment: alright, I think I updated the answer to be true now.... boy that was complicated!

Comment: @zerkms we really have to separate between syntax and values here.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan "A value is what an identifier may evaluate to. " --- why do you refer to it as an identifier? It's a value already. "The spec didn't completely defined undefined" --- it defines `undefined` as a primitive **value**, as well as `null`

Comment: @zerkms why not? :) A "variable" implies a varying value. An identifier may be a variable or a constant, which doesn't vary.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan "why not" --- because a standard defines it as a "primitive value"

Comment: @zerkms as I said, you have to keep the distinction between `undefined` the *syntax* and `undefined` the *value*. I think I'm over with this discussion.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan I clearly understand the distinction. `null` - could you please tell what it is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69855/discussion-between-zerkms-and-ionu-g-stan).

Comment: @zerkms sorry, I don't _feel_ it'll be a productive discussion.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Well, I see. Okay, seems like the opinion based on a standard is not popular these days and people operate with their feelings instead. :-)

Comment: "and undefined is a variable containing the primitive value" --- sorry, this is plain **WRONG**. It's not required to be a variable and is clearly an implementation-specific thing. "containing the primitive value `Undefined`" --- this is wrong as well, there is no such primitive value defined by ES standard.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan guys, seriously, why do you spread wrong information? I seriously cannot understand it :-(

Comment: @zerkms it's not wrong, it's just hard to see the difference between `undefined` the variable name, `undefined` the value and `Undefined` the type.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan it's not hard. First step is to realize: there is no such variable. Then it's trivial

Comment: @zerkms yes, it's not a variable, it's a property name of the Global object. That makes it an identifier, every property name must an identifier. Take a look at this link which has already been shared: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3

Comment: @zerkms so, yeah, I retract my statement that `undefined` as a syntax hasn't been properly defined by the standard. It has been, it's an object property. Please, don't freak out now. :)

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan it's a property of a global object, but interpreter **IS NOT REQUIRED** to use it, since `undefined` is already a primitive value. So as per standard interpreter may resolve this token directly into a value.

Comment: @zerkms if it's listed in the standard, then it's required. Ok, now I'm really done with this discussion. You still can't make the difference between syntax and values produced by result of evaluation. Sorry.

Comment: "if it's listed in the standard, then it's required" --- nope. It's there but interpreter is not obliged to use it. I'm surprised that people cannot just read what is written without mixing it with their assumptions. "You still can't make the difference between syntax and values" --- you can.